# Async random letter generation too fast

Tags: c#, asynchronous, random, generator

I know that there's a problem with generators in that they are sometimes too fast and end up generating the same character twice, or not generating at all. I'm creating a program that generates random characters and I wanted to include a progress bar which I was going to implement using asynchronous generation.

The problem is that it won't generate correctly because it's generating too fast. I'll tell it to generate 3 sets of characters and it will do 1, or 5 sets and it will do 2.

How do I slow it down and allow it to generate asynchronously, or how do I implement a working progress bar some other way?

Here's some of my code:

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    string result;
    bool failed = false;

    int amount = Convert.ToInt32(numMassGen.Value),
        initialAmount = amount;

     while(0 < amount--) {
        result = Generate(rand).Result;

        if(result != "failed") {
            WriteToFile(result, initialAmount - amount);
            statusText.Text = "Finished generating and saving " + (initialAmount - amount) + "/" + initialAmount + " keys."; 
        }
        else {
            UpdateStatus("Not enough options selected for this length.");
            failed = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!failed) {
        UpdateStatus("Finished generating and saving " + numMassGen.Value + " keys.");
    }
}

private Task WriteToFile(string result, int completed) {
    return WriteToFileAsync(result);
}

private async Task WriteToFileAsync(string result) {
    byte[] resultEncoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result + Environment.NewLine);

    using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(txtSaveLocation.Text,
        FileMode.Append,
        FileAccess.Write,
        FileShare.None,
        bufferSize: 4096,
        useAsync: true)) {
            await stream.WriteAsync(resultEncoded, 0, resultEncoded.Length);
    }
}

// This method's probably crude, it's a little old and I don't know
// how to improve it.
// This is also where the problems occur. When I step through this code,
// it's slowing down the random generation.
// When I run it normally, it's too fast and skips generating.
private async Task<string> GenerateAsync(Random rand) {
    string sAll = "", result = "", sLower, sUpper, sNumbers, sHyphen, sUnderscore, sSpace, sSpecial, sBrackets;
    int length = Convert.ToInt32(numSections.Value) * Convert.ToInt32(numCharacters.Value),
        initialLength = length;
    char character;

    sLower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    sUpper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    sNumbers = "0123456789";
    sHyphen = "-";
    sUnderscore = "_";
    sSpace = " ";
    sSpecial = "`~!@#$%^&*()+=\\|/?.,;:'\"";
    sBrackets = "()[]{}<>";

    if(Properties.Settings.Default.charUppercase)
        sAll += sUpper;
    if(Properties.Settings.Default.charLowercase)
        sAll += sLower;
    if(Properties.Settings.Default.charNumbers)
        sAll += sNumbers;
    if(Properties.Settings.Default.charUnderscore)
        sAll += sUnderscore;
    if(Properties.Settings.Default.charSpace)
        sAll += sSpace;
    if(Properties.Settings.Default.charSpecial)
        sAll += sSpecial;
    if(Properties.Settings.Default.charBrackets)
        sAll += sBrackets;

    while(0 < length) {
        if(sAll.Length == 0) {
            return "failed";
        }

        character = sAll[rand.Next(sAll.Length)];

        if(Properties.Settings.Default.charRepeat) {
            sAll = sAll.Remove(sAll.IndexOf(character), 1);
        }

        if((length % Properties.Settings.Default.secCharacters == 0) && (length != 0) && (length != initialLength)) {
            result += sHyphen;
        }

        result += character;

        length--;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: if possible you can lock an object. Or you will need to build a throttling mechanism. Depends more on the design of your system

Comment: Show us, what You tried so far.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Can you post some code?

Comment: It is totally not clear what you are talking about. Where do you know that "generators generate same character twice". What's the source of your assumption?

Comment: @Samuel So sorry about that... I've had a rough day. I've posted some (hopefully clear) code and explained it in some comments. I previously asked a question, or Googled, why my randomly-generated characters would sometimes occur twice in a row, and some answers said it was because the process was running too fast and it needed time to generate another character.

Comment: Declare rand as a static variable and use a mutex/locking to ensure it can only be called by 1 thread at a time.  It should produce uniformly distributed results.

Answer (score 3):

From your comment

> why my randomly-generated characters would sometimes occur twice in a row, and some answers said it was because the process was running too fast and it needed time to generate another character.

This would usually happen if you create a new instance of a `Random` class in short space of time and request new value from it (most likely in a loop). In this case, each new `Random` object may get the same *seed* from current system clock and may produce the same pseudorandom number. This is how most pseudorandom generators work by design.

However, if you use *the same instance* of `Random` class (and this is what you should do), this is not possible (with one note, see below). It is due to the `Random` class's ability to take into account its previous state.

Be aware, that **random does not equal unique**.

It is absolutely possible for a pseudorandom number generator to produce sequence of the same numbers. For example, if you only have a choice of 0 or 1, RNG *may* produce sequence containing only zeros: `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...`. The probability of each one being a 0 is 50%, which may, in some long running experiment produce you a sequence of desired length containing all zeros. This could take really looooong time, but it is possible.

To answer your question:

- Understand the difference between *random* (this allows duplicates, but gives you next value using uniform distribution) and *unique* (doesn't allow duplicates, can use any distribution)
- Use only a single instance of `Random` class throughout or better [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx)
- Speed of generation must be irrelevant in correct implementation, as the next value will depend on the previous state
- Make it work syncronously, then switch to async (but frankly you don't need async here)
- `Random` is not thread safe

Comment: How would I go about doing this safely? I want to really generate something entirely random--or is that impossible?

Comment: @Abluescarab if you want strong random noise, just use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` on Windows. There are 3rd party libraries that provide good noise. I cannot recommend exact one, but I think if you search for `cryptographic random number generator open source c#` this should get you going.